# How to add extra EXIF data when images are uploaded?

Tags: plugin-development, attachments, media-modal

I have a function to add EXIF information to an image after the image is uploaded to a website. How do I get the EXIF information to be automatically added to the image after the image is uploaded or added to the post?

I have tried some hooks like the following to check for failed photo uploads and started executing the function to add EXIF info but it doesn't work. `add_attachment`, `wp_handle_upload` and `wp_handle_upload_prefilter`. Whenever an image is uploaded through adding to the post, it gives an error that the image could not be uploaded.

Below is an example of my code. Every time I select an image to add to a post, I get a message like this. Please help me.
Thank you very much!

> *An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.*

```
function custom_to_all_image($upload) {
    if (wp_attachment_is_image($attachment_id)) {
      //my function
    }
    return $upload;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'custom', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: A filter only changes existing data - the problem is likely that you're trying to echo. Try writing to a log file instead - something that doesn't directly output data to the browser.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to `echo` on image upload as those happen during AJAX calls and there'd be no way to see your output, it'd also break the AJAX response! That's why the post editor says image could not be uploaded. What are you trying to do that requires this? It sounds like an X Y problem were you asked how to implement your fix not how to solve the problem. I read the initial few sentences that try to explain this but it didn't make much sense. What does reprocessing do? Are you trying to optimise images? Making your Q more specific will get you more/better answers

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm just giving an example so people can imagine my purpose, not me calling echo. :( What I need is this, I want the image after uploading to add some EXIF attributes and to do this I need to recreate the image.The image reconstruction I tested when running the separate function it worked successfully, just now I don't know how to check when the image is successfully uploaded to the website to start executing the function to add the EXIF attribute and recreate the image.

Comment: ah then you should ask how to add extra EXIF data when images are uploaded, that's much easier to understand and answer, as it's very specific. You should edit your question to refocus it on adding EXIF data on upload

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you! I have edited my question again

Comment: @KelvinNgo I see you edited it again and added code that makes it work, if you've found a solution can you post it as an answer below instead of editing it into your question so that it can be marked as the correct answer and upvoted?

Comment: @TomJNowell I fixed it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Edited code to make it work**

```
function proccess_to_all_image($file) {
    $file_path = $file['file'];
    $mime_type = $file['type'];
    $id = attachment_url_to_postid($file['url']);
    if (preg_match('/^image\/[a-z\-]+$/i', $mime_type)) {
      *//call to function here*
    }
    return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'proccess_to_all_image', 10, 2);
```